# Could Sauron have made another ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Was there anything stopping Sauron from making another "one ring"? Was he too weak since his separation from the ring to craft another? Or would it have taken a long time?

Comment: That sounds like an excellent mum solution to the War of the Ring.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Either that or putting Sauron on the naughty step...

Comment: The problem is, how would he have had to call it? The Two Ring?

Comment: "For the less even as for the greater there is some deed that he may accomplish but once only; and in that deed his heart shall rest. It may be that I can unlock my jewels, but never again shall I make their like; and if I must break them, I shall break my heart, and I shall be slain; first of all the Eldar in Aman." -- applies to Sauron just as much as Feanor and Yawanna.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The quick answer is, "Yes, he was too weak." In Gandalf's words:

> This is the One Ring that he lost many ages ago, to the great weakening of his power.

Now how, exactly, you want to interpret that might vary. After all, Sauron was certainly powerful enough to "reconstitute" himself, reorganize his armies, and sweep back into Mordor relatively early in the Third Age. But the Ring contained him, in a sense:

> ... it is his, and he let a great part of his own former power pass into it, so that he could rule all the others. (Gandalf)

(both quotes from *The Fellowship Of The Ring*, Chapter 2, "The Shadow Of The Past")

Even without the Ring, he still had the ability to control the others: in particular the rings of the Nazgûl.  But it's at best highly questionable, as I read the material, whether he had enough power to create another Ring of the same power as the first.

Comment: Good answer. He probably could have made a lesser ring but there was no point. He would have diffused his already greatly reduced personal power even further and would have only had a lesser ring to show for it.

Comment: He didn't really reconstitute. One could say he was but a shadow of his former self... pun intended :-)

Answer (score 10):

Sauron placed an enormous amount of his own "*strength and will*" into the One Ring in order to make it powerful enough to dominate the [3, 7 and 9 rings](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Rings_of_Power). Although it's not explicitly stated, the fact that he expended vast resources on a search for the Ring over hundreds of years would strongly suggest that making another ring simply isn't an option.

More importantly, the One Ring was invested with sufficient power to rule **all the other magic rings** in Middle Earth. Since Sauron knows that the One Ring (described in the Silmarillion as a device of "surpassing potency") is still knocking about, if he made another less powerful ring to wear then he could find himself subject to the will of whoever wields the One Ring. That was something he absolutely couldn't risk.

> Now the Elves made many rings; but secretly Sauron made One Ring to
>   rule all the others, and their power was bound up with it, to be
>   subject wholly to it and to last only so long as it too should last.
>   And **much of the strength and will of Sauron passed into that One Ring**;
>   for the power of the Elven-rings was very great, **and that which should
>   govern them must be a thing of surpassing potency**; and Sauron forged
>   it in the Mountain of Fire in the Land of Shadow. And while he wore
>   the One Ring he could perceive all the things that were done by means
>   of the lesser rings, and he could see and govern the very thoughts of
>   those that wore them.
>   <sub><sup>**(The Silmarillion)**</sup></sub>

Comment: That's a bit speculative. We know the One Ring was made to rule over the *existing* rings, but there's nothing that really implies that any *future* rings, created by someone aware of the One and its powers, will be subservient to it. I always thought it was a form of back-door he planted into the rings the Elves made.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - The three Elven rings were "free of Sauron's influence" but still subject to the One Ring because they were made using the same techniques; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Rings. It follows that any future rings would also be subject to the One Ring.

Comment: Quite the opposite, I think. Any ring made after the One Ring is exposed - especially by a skilled crafter like Sauron - could be made free of that influence. There's nothing to indicate that the flaw is intrinsic to all rings by their nature, only to the specific (purposefully flawed) technique taught by Sauron.

Comment: @Richard It follows that new rings made using the same techniques would be under the control of the One, but perhaps there are other ways to make rings. And if anyone could figure out how to do so, it would be Sauron; he was the one who taught Celebrimbor how to make rings in the first place so clearly he is an expert in ring-crafting.

Comment: @DavidZ - The idea that Sauron could make an even more powerful One Ring, but that wasn't subject to the existing One Ring and yet still capable of controlling the other Rings of Power is a huge leap of the imagination.

Comment: @Richard I only argue that one cannot necessarily conclude that any new ring Sauron might make would be subject to the influence of the One Ring. It does stand to reason that a new ring would have been weaker.

Comment: @DavidZ - We only see Sauron using one technique to make rings. Rings made using that technique are subject to the will of the One Ring. If Sauron makes a lesser ring, it seems likely that that ring would be subject to the One Ring. I fail to see what logical step I've missed...

Comment: Just a note that "Elven-rings" as used in the quotation here refers to all the rings forged by the Elves (the Three, the Seven, and the Nine, as well as the "lesser rings" Gandalf refers to), not to the rings forged _for_ the elves (Narya, Nenya, Vilya).

Comment: @MattGutting - True, but the elves also perceived that their existing rings would have been subject to the One Ring; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Rings

Comment: Technically "if Sauron makes a lesser ring _by the same process_, it seems likely that that ring would be subject to the One Ring." I think that @DavidZ is making the point that if Sauron used a different process, the result might not be subject to it. WRT my comment: I was just pointing that out because it's a confusion I'm often subject to, and I thought it might arise in others.

Comment: The idea that some of Sauron's "magical substance" or whatever the scientifically accurate term is was put into the One Ring is compelling. Not only does that explain why he could not make another but also perhaps why it was crucial to get it back and it would also account for the Ring's superhuman intelligence -- it bound up some of Sauron himself. How crazy it is for someone to want to wear such an object -- it is very much like, I think JRRT intended, a dangerous drug like opium.